# Traversing a vector vs array which one is faster?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

While traversing a vector and a array which one is faster and helpful in compititive programming?

Comment: **traversing** is a really broad term here, it does not say what you do in that step. For an `std::array` the size is known at compile-time, for `std::vector` it is not, so for a `std::array` the compiler could, in theory, do optimizations for the `std::array` base on that size information. In general, you choose the container that fits the use-case the best.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. But an array is faster to create because it has a fixed size

Comment: You can't do any assumptions about the performance differences based on such a broad description. That the data is stored continuously is just one factor. But possible optimizations do not depend on this alone.

Answer (score 0):

They are equal in speed because the underlying data is in both cases a contiguous block of memory where only a simple pointer arithmetics is needed to move to arbitrary element.

Comment: You can't do any assumptions about the performance differences based on such a broad description. That the data is stored continuously is just one factor. But possible optimizations do not depend on this alone.